# Sharing PHP session from subdomain to TLD

Tags: php, session

There is session data being saved on `sub.domain.com` and I'd like to use that data in `domain.com`.

I confirmed that they both have the same session save path (by echoing `ini_get('session.save_path')` in both)

I've tried putting `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.sub.domain');` on domain.com but that didn't work. (I have also removed the preceding `.`).

I also tried adding `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');` in front of each `session_start()`, but that didn't work either.

I would like to be able to use the `$_SESSION` data in `domain.com` from what is set in `sub.domain.com`.

What can I do for this to work?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**: I figured out (at least one way) of how to do this, but not sure why my answer works. I guess my question would now be, Why does renaming the session name solve this? using the same session cookie domain (?) makes more sense to me.

---

Seems like setting this domain creates a new session `$_SESSION['domain']` (where 'domain' is interchangeable in the `session_name('domain')` function.)

Answer (score 2):

adding the following to each file fixed this:

```
session_name("domain");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

**Does anyone know why re-naming the session fixes this?** It's that first line that made this all work.